# Avoid cache misses

Tags: c, pthreads

Given two Arrays, say A and B that each contain an amount of about 10^7 elements (Any C base Type but most probably int and char with 4 Bytes). 
I am going to split these arrays into smaller pieces (depending on available cores in the CPU) and merge them. Do I have to expect Cache misses?

In my understanding Cache misses appear if two blocks of data are very close together in memory and every core loads this data in it's L1 Cache.
For example assume Core1 which runs ThreadA and Core2 which runs ThreadB.

Then a write Operation is perforemd on data in Cache (Core1) by Thread A and the CPU has to assume that it's Cache Data (Core2) in Thread B is not coherent anymore. So it has to reload the whole Cache from the RAM which is slow.

As I will only read from Array A and B I thought that would be no problem, but I have stumbled upon some other questions where Cache miss due to reading data seems to be a problem.

But even then - Cache misses would be minimal I guess.

For example assume Zero to be data in the Array and | the seperator between the chunks that will be processed by the Threads.

00000000 **0|0** 0000000 **0|0** 000000 **0|0** 00000000|

My guess is that only small parts at the seperator would be affected, but since I am going to work with big data most of the time it can't be that bad.

Only to my target Array C will be written from multiple threads - do I have to expect Performance issues here?

So my Questions are:

- Does Cache incoherence occure during read Actions?
- How could one determine Cache misses (except by logic)
- Merging doesn't seem to be kinda vulnerable to Cache misses, but my Professor told us that we have to expect this -  which I can't really understand.

Reading articles on this Topic did not satisfy me 100% since I didn't find a definite answer to my first question.

EDIT: Added size of stored elements.

Comment: Yes, you need to expect cache misses some of the time. You don't say how big the elements in the arrays are, but if they're integers or floats (4 bytes each), you'll have 80 million bytes or so being used, and your caches might be big enough to hold them all eventually, but until they're in cache, there'll be misses. If you have 256 MiB L2 cache, it may all be in there.  If you're dealing with 256 byte elements, it won't all be in the L2 cache.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : Thanks for the quick reply! Will edit my question properly.
So if I read data I will have Cache misses too. Does it make sense to store data blocks with a big enough Offset to each other or will I just live with the misses? 
I know that Cache misses will probably be the smallest perfomance issues that will occure (thread creation will be much bigger I guess), yet it's the most exciting one.

Comment: As long as data that you read is close to its other `eg an array,` you avoid cache misses. Thats because cpu loads `chunks of bytes` eg 64bytes at a time. 64 may vary.

Comment: @valter: You can't avoid compulsory cache misses...

Comment: You are conflating two things here.  Cache coherence is to do with ensuring a consistent view of the world in a multi-processor scenario. Cache hits/misses are a concern even in a single-processor world.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth : Okay I see the point of your comment when reading this: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Microprocessor_Design/Cache#Hit_or_Miss but still... It is very likely that my data will be stored in the Cache so it's very likely the cores will find their data. But: What exactly is the Thing I look for then (Cache miss BECAUSE of data incoherence e.g when the CPU decides that it's Cache is not up to date any more because one core did change data the others use too)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I didnt meant no misses at all. Just less.